# window.location working only on index page

Tags: javascript, html, window.location

I've read the similar questions on SO but none of them helps.

I have this JS

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {



          var txt = $('#srch').val();

    if (txt.toUpperCase() === "abc".toUpperCase()){

      window.location= "http://somepage.html";



    }
}
});
```

Its redirecting only on the index page. On the rest of the pages it's not redirecting. It's only putting  a "?" on the end of the current URL.

Comment: It will only redirect to `http://somepage.html`. What do you expect?

Comment: the problem is it doesn't redirect

Comment: You have this code on all of your pages? What error do you get  in your browser's console for the pages where it does not work?

Answer (score 0):

Check console (and code):

1. any earlier error blocking your code
2. input#srch exists in every page
3. is an https page requesting a non https page? (mixed content blocked by browser)
4. your js code exists in every page
5. does exist an earlier bind to same input#srch?
6. url is always the same or is dynamic? if so, is correctly populated?

Comment: I checked all suggestions but that's not the case. If i put an alert right after

  `   if (txt.toUpperCase() === "abc".toUpperCase()){
alert("works"); `

its firing so its all working except the actual redirect.

Comment: Can you provide an url?

Comment: sorry, I can't for security reasons. I tried to redirect to google.com but still the same. the only thing that happens when I press enter is its adding a "?" at the end of the current URL

Comment: Can you try with different browsers? Same behaviour?

Comment: It works in firefox but its not working in chrome and Edge

Comment: try replacing 
window.location = 'http://....';

with
window.location.href = 'http://....';
or
window.location.assign('http://....');

Answer (score 0):

It was working in firefox but not in chrome and edge. I added return false; like this

```
 window.location= "http://somepage.html"; return false;
```

Now it works for all browsers. Thanks to Diego Betto for pointing me in the right direction.